# Algorithm for solving the game 'Pop it' in least steps

Tags: algorithm

Can anyone suggest me a strategy for solving this game http://puzzle-games.pogo.com/games/poppit in least possible steps.

My idea is to find the group of balloons (same-colored neighbours) which after being removed leaves us with the fewest number of groups.

My implementation however, is not good enough. The only thing I can think of is collect all groups of balloons and check for each group what would be the number of groups left if I remove it. This of course is quite heavy operation to do since it includes rearranging the balloons after I remove a group and then restoring the original order.

If someone comes up with a better way of implementing my algorithm or a completely other approach to the problem, I would be really thankful!

Answer (score 1):

This game is another version of [Same Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SameGame).  The question of whether an optimal solution exists was shown in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs.CC/0107031) to be NP complete.  What this means is that in general,
an optimal solution will take exponential time to find.  On the other hand, if you turn the problem into an instance of the boolean satisfiability problem, you may be able to use a [SAT solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT) to solve the problem more quickly than an ad-hoc approach.

Answer (score 0):

What you have mentioned is the [Backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) approach. You pop groups of balloons until you can't no more, then you undo the the last move and try something else. Wikipedia explains this better than I ever could.

While this sounds computationally heavy, I'm guessing computers these days should be able to solve your problem pretty quickly.

As for implementation, base it on a recursive function (a function that calls itself), the pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
void main()
{
    setupBoard();
    if(Try())
        print("Found Solution");
}

boolean Try()
{
   if(noballonsLeft)
       return true; //Found solution!
   foreach(Move move in getPossibleMoves())
   {
       doMove(move);
       if(Try())
           return true; //This try found a solution!
       undoMove(move);
   }
   return false; //No solutions found
}
```

This will find *a* solution to the problem, extending this to find the best solution should be no problem ;)